# React Native can't read Database Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

**I can't read database to insert in 'Text'. I'm using Redux**

Json

```
DiasSemana
 |
 |__Quarta: "Test Program"
 |
 |__Quinta: "nothing"
 |
 |
```

Class EstudoDia.js  I used mapStateToProps, connect and import actions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { estudoDoDia } from "../actions/AutenticacaoActions";

export class estudoDia extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    //I've tried with 'this.props.quarta' and it didn't work
    props.estudoDia(props.quarta);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{props.quarta}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  quarta: state.AutenticacaoReducer.quarta
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { estudoDoDia })(estudoDia);
```

types.js

```
export const MATERIA_DO_DIA = 'materia_do_dia';
```

ActionReducer.js. I import types and return payload

```
import { MATERIA_DO_DIA } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  quarta: "T.I Program"
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case MATERIA_DO_DIA:
      return { ...state, quarta: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

AutenticacaoActions.js. Used snaphot

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import { MATERIA_DO_DIA } from "./types";

export const estudoDoDia = quarta => {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase.database
      .ref("/DiasSemana/Quarta")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        quarta = snapshot.val();
        dispatch({
          type: MATERIA_DO_DIA,
          payload: snapshot.val
        });
      });
  };
};
```

have image in link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSFCt.png)

thank you if you can help me

Comment: There are a lot of pieces involved here, which makes it hard to help. Simplest question to help debug. If you put a breakpoint on `quarta = snapshot.val();` and run in a debugger, does it hit that breakpoint? And if so, does `quarta` have the value you expect it to have?

Comment: Where is your database initialization? You just imported import firebase from 'firebase'; without initializing it.

Comment: Also, try changing once to on

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 
so that was the biggest problem, it didn't even reach that point of the fourth = snapshot.val (), but I managed to modify this function

Comment: @dhanushkac 
If you have placed this logo on the first screen so that it can be initialized as soon as you start an application, and do an import correctly, you will find out which error is or is not using the snapshot method. on instead of once was a good attempt.

Comment: Okay. I am from React. Not React-native. Just checked If there is any help I can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank you all for your help, in case I discovered that the problem is in the estudoDoDia method in AuthenticationActions.js, I made this change and it worked

```
export const estudoDoDia = (quarta) => {    
    return dispatch => {

        firebase.database().ref('DiasSemana/Quarta').once('value', function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val())
            quarta = snapshot.toJSON();

 dispatch(
{
    type: MATERIA_DO_DIA,
    payload: quarta
})  
})
 }
}
```

Inside once I made it call a function passing the snapshop as a parameter and it worked.
I thank you for your help and thank you all